# R if else code for combining two variables into one

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I have two variables - Small_Vehicle and Large_Vehicle which are coded as 0 and 1s. I want to combine them into one variable where if the vehicle was small - 1, and if it was large - 2. If there is no data, I want R to leave is as NA. I have written the code below but it gives me the error:

Error: unexpected '}' in "    TRIdata$Combined <- NA }"

The Combined variable already exists in the dataset but has the wrong values currently.

```
if (TRIdata$Small_Vehicle = 1) {
TRIdata$Combined<-1 } else {
if (TRIdata$Large_Vehicle=1)  {
TRIdata$Combined<-2 } else {
TRIdata$Combined <- NA }}
```

Do you have any suggestions about what I am doing wrong, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Use == instead of = with comparison operators

Comment: Hello Monika. Welcome to StackOverflow. The `if()` function in R should resolve to a single value of TRUE or FALSE. Since `TRIdata$Small_Vehicle` is a vector, after correcting the `=` vs `==` error in the code, it will fail with a warning that *condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.* You'll need to implement an approach that uses vectorized calculations, or loop through the values one by one. Vectorized operations are faster than looping. My answer contains two different approaches with vectorized calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `small_vehicle` and `large_vehicle` are mutually exclusive and exhaustive categories, we can create `Combined` without if / then logic as follows.

```
small_vehicle <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
large_vehicle <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1)

TRIdata <- data.frame(small_vehicle,large_vehicle)
TRIdata$Combined <- 2*TRIdata$large_vehicle + small_vehicle

TRIdata
```

...and the output:

```
> TRIdata
  small_vehicle large_vehicle Combined
1             1             0        1
2             0             1        2
3             0             1        2
4             1             0        1
5             1             0        1
6             1             0        1
7             0             1        2
>
```

### Alternate approach

We can do the same thing with `ifelse()`.

```
# alternate approach 
small_vehicle <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
large_vehicle <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1)

TRIdata <- data.frame(small_vehicle,large_vehicle)
TRIdata$Combined <- ifelse(TRIdata$small_vehicle == 1,1,2)
TRIdata
```

...and the output.

```
> TRIdata
  small_vehicle large_vehicle Combined
1             1             0        1
2             0             1        2
3             0             1        2
4             1             0        1
5             1             0        1
6             1             0        1
7             0             1        2
>
```

### Why doesn't the original code work?

I'll illustrate my comment on the original post with the following code. We'll correct the `=` vs. `==` error in the original, and then attempt to run it.

```
# original code with my sample data
small_vehicle <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
large_vehicle <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1)
TRIdata <- data.frame(Small_Vehicle = small_vehicle,
                      Large_Vehicle = large_vehicle)

if (TRIdata$Small_Vehicle == 1) {
     TRIdata$Combined <- 1
} else {
     if (TRIdata$Large_Vehicle == 1)  {
          TRIdata$Combined <- 2
     } else {
          TRIdata$Combined <- NA
     }
}
```

...produces the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (TRIdata$Small_Vehicle == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
```

When we print the results, we observe that R evaluated the first element of `TRIdata$Small_Vehicle` as TRUE, and assigned the value of 1 to every element in `TRIdata$Combined`.

```
> TRIdata
  Small_Vehicle Large_Vehicle Combined
1             1             0        1
2             0             1        1
3             0             1        1
4             1             0        1
5             1             0        1
6             1             0        1
7             0             1        1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (TRIdata$Small_Vehicle == 1) {
    TRIdata$Combined<-1 } elseif (TRIdata$Large_Vehicle=1) {
    TRIdata$Combined<-2 } else {
    TRIdata$Combined <- NA }
```

Comment: this, as in the op, will cause problems in the `if` statment as  a vector is getting passed. I suppose it could be wrapped in a `for` statement and the vectors indexed (`[i]`), or use `ifelse`.

Comment: This code fragment contains multiple errors. First, the `elseif` is not an R control construct,. Second, its argument has `=` instead of `==` and third,  after correcting these errors, it will produce inaccurate results as noted by @user20650 .